# Visual Studio 10 TFS giving Interop error when opening TFS query in Excel

Tags: visual-studio-2010, excel

[image: TFS Excel Automation error]

When I try to open a TFS query (work items) in Excel from Visual Studio I get the following error.

Visual Studio 2010 Premium, TFS 2010 and Office 2013.  This was working last week but has stopped working.  I suspect some kind of Office update has caused this but I have not been able to locate how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was bugs with the products which Microsoft released more patches for that fixed the issue.